# Recreating RDS with Terraform automatically

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, aws-code-deploy

I want terraform to re-create RDS cluster everytime I run terraform.

I am using `aws_rds_cluster` and `aws_rds_cluster_instance` to create postgres RDS cluster using CodeDeploy. The code works.

However, when re-deploying the code 2nd time (with CodeDeploy), get the error: DBClusterAlreadyExistsFault - which is true.

What can I do so that everytime I run terraform or my pipeline, terraform destroys the current RDS cluster and creates a new one.

Is there even such a thing?

I have looked into force_destroy parameter, but this parameter is for aws_rds_global_cluster and not for aws_rds_cluster

(Currently, I am deleting the database manually through AWS console before running terraform again)
Thanks for your help

Comment: Store your state in S3+DynamoDB and run a `terraform destroy` during your pipeline. Unclear why you would want that but that is how it would work, terraform would never just destroy resources it does not manage.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to be [storing the state in S3](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3) so that Terraform knows what resources it is managing between runs. However the recommendation to use `terraform destroy` will destroy **everything**, not just the RDS instance. If you have anything else in the Terraform state then you probably don't want to run `terraform destroy`. The

Terraform feature for triggering Terraform to delete and re-create specific resources is the `terraform apply -replace` command, (previously [terraform taint](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/taint)).